# How to send the data I got from modal to the main view?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, modalviewcontroller

```
app.controller('FilterController', ['$scope', '$http',
function($scope,$http) {

    //Loading the data to the filter scope
    $http.get('/main').success(function(response){
        $scope.data = response;
    });

    //The object that the input fields in the modal bind to
    $scope.selected = {};

    this.applyFilter = function(){
        $http.post('/main/query', $scope.selected).success(function(response){
            //The response is the filtered object sent by the server
            console.log(response); //This is the response I want to bind to the main view

            //Do something to pass the response to the main scope

        });
    };
}]);
```

The modal includes some drop downs for users to pick the parameters and these parameters are saved to the 'selected' variable, which is in turn sent to the database to query a new set of data.
The challenge now is to send this new data to the main scope and refresh the page. I did some research and found that it seems like it can be done by resolve, but I am not sure exactly how to put the code together. Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with angular-ui i'll suppose you are using ui.bootstrap for modals.

First inject [ui.bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) to your app.

In your main controller you open the modal:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$modal',
function($scope,$modal) {
    $scope.filterModal = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        controller: 'FilterController',
        size: 'md'
    });
    $scope.filterModal.result.then(function (result) {
        // do what you have to with result from modal
    });
}]);
```

Your modal must have a controller:

```
app.controller('FilterController', ['$scope', '$http','$modalInstance',
function($scope,$http, $modalInstance) {

    //Loading the data to the filter scope
    $http.get('/main').success(function(response){
        $scope.data = response;
    });

    //The object that the input fields in the modal bind to
    $scope.selected = {};

    this.applyFilter = function(){
        $http.post('/main/query', $scope.selected).success(function(response){
            //The response is the filtered object sent by the server
            console.log(response); //This is the response I want to bind to the main view

            //Do something to pass the response to the main scope
            $modalInstance.close(response);
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: went back and study the example again and finally realize it is the  $modalInstance.close() method that is doing the magic, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by simply assigning the $scope.data to the response.

```
    this.applyFilter = function(){
        $http.post('/main/query', $scope.selected).success(function(response){
            //The response is the filtered object sent by the server
            console.log(response); //This is the response I want to bind to the main view

            // Binding the response
            $scope.data = response;

            //Do something to pass the response to the main scope

        });
    };
```